# UIButton with template image receiving touch events only for non-transparent pixels

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an iOS app written in Swift (2.1). I'm using a little workaround which I've found to make smaller margins between UIBarButtonItem's in NavigationBar. Here's my code:

```
    let modeImage = UIImage(named: modeFilename)!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    modeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22))
    modeButton.setBackgroundImage(modeImage, forState: .Normal)
    modeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("modeClicked:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    modeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 0)
    let modeButtonContainer = UIView(frame: modeButton.frame)
    modeButtonContainer.addSubview(modeButton)
    modeButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: modeButtonContainer)
```

Button works, but I have a square-like simple image and touch is only working on non-transparent pixels (or near them maybe). It's hard to hit it on simulator not to mention real device. It's a real pain. I've found solution to use Tap Gesture Recognizer on modeButtonContainer, but then button is not hovering so it's not a best solution.

Using setImage instead of setBackgroundImage doesn't change anything. Same goes for creating button with type UIButtonType.Custom.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! My theory was wrong. It's not because of transparent pixels. Problem causes this line:

```
modeButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, 0)
```

This caused button to be offsetted by 10 points instead being at center of its container. Button seemed looking good, but when I've set background to modeButtonContainer I realized button work only on containers area and doesn't work outside it.

So I needed to remove this line and instead use add this as first item in rightBarButtonItems:

```
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeSpacer.width = -10
```